# function changes upon condition

Tags: function-construction, syntax, conditional

I have the function

```
f[x_,y_]:=1/(Sin[x]+Sin[y])
```

which obviously becomes infinite for $x=\pi n, \;y=\pi n$ where $n\,\epsilon \, \mathbf{N}$.
I want to give `f` the value `0` for this case, i.e `f[x,y]=0`

I am trying

```
While[Mod[x, π] == 0 && Mod[y, π] == 0, f[x, y] == 0]
```

but it doesn't work.

I also tried

```
f[x_ /; Mod[x, π] == 0, y_ /; Mod[y, π]] := 0
```

didn't work either

How can I do it?

Comment: For $y=-x$ your function is also `ComplexInfinity`. Do you want to similarly treat this case?

Comment: @yarchik I didn't need that for what I had in mind, but now that you mention it why not? Please post your answer

Comment: Your solution below is good. In  the case you want to make sure that there is no overflow you can do something like `f[x_, y_] := If[Sin[x] + Sin[y] == 0, 0, 1/(Sin[x] + Sin[y])]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] := 0 /; Mod[x, π] == 0 && Mod[y, π] == 0
```

does the trick. Just figured it.

Any comments are most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Piecewise` definition as well:

```
Clear[f]
f[x_, y_] := 
   Piecewise[
     {{1/(Sin[x] + Sin[y]), Mod[x, Pi] != 0 || Mod[y, Pi] != 0}}, 
     0
   ]

f[2, 3.]      (* 0.952002 *)
f[Pi, 3 Pi]   (* 0        *)
f[2, 10 Pi]   (* Csc[2]   *)
f[Pi, 2 Pi]   (* 0        *)
```

Here I made the default value $0$ explicit for future code readability, but technically `Piecewise` already defaults to $0$ if none of the conditions are met, so you could omit it.